# Display Customer Attribute on Fronted My Account

Tags: php, magento-2.3

I tried display customer attribute on frontend from admin. But I dont know how to display it, because attribute is type "select" and when I got value of it I got value of option of source model.

***My layout ArseniyInk/TaskTwo/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml***

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <container name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer.account.dashboard.info.extra.magento.username" template="ArseniyInk_TaskTwo::account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

***My Source Model ArseniyInk/TaskTwo/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source/Employment.php***

```
<?php

namespace ArseniyInk\TaskTwo\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source;

class Employment extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __('Unemployment'), 'value' => '1'],
            ['label' => __('Pupil'), 'value' => '2'],
            ['label' => __('Student'), 'value' => '3'],
            ['label' => __('Employee'), 'value' => '4']
            ];
        }
    return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

***My Attribute ArseniyInk/TaskTwo/Setup/Patch/Data/AddTestEmploymentAttribute.php***

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Patch to create Customer Attribute
 *
 * 
 */

namespace ArseniyInk\TaskTwo\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Zend_Validate_Exception;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class AddTestEmploymentAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param Config              $eavConfig
     * @param EavSetupFactory     $eavSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $eavConfig,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Create account customer attribute
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'new_test_employment', [
            'type'             => 'int',
            'input'            => 'select',
            'source'           => 'ArseniyInk\TaskTwo\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Employment',
            'label'            => 'NEmployment',
            'visible'          => false,
            'required'         => false,
            'user_defined'     => true,
            'system'           => false,
            'global'           => true,
            'default'          => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'sort_order'       => 52,
            'position'         => 52
        ]);

        $customAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'new_test_employment');

        $customAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
        ]);
        $customAttribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

***My Template ArseniyInk/TaskTwo/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml***

```
<p>
    Employment =
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('new_test_employment')->getValue()) ?><br>
</p>
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V12SY.jpg)